# If a grid item the width of which is 0px contains an element of 0px width with left margin greater than 0px it overflows the grid container in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-grid

If a grid item the width of which is 0px
contains an element of 0px width with "margin-left" css property value greater than 0
and is placed on a grid column track the size of which is "auto"
then it overflows the grid container in Firefox browser.

If the width of the grid item is any greater than 0px (even 0.1px) then it does not overflow the grid container.
The grid item overflows only if "grid-template-columns" is specified for grid container as "1fr auto" and the grid item is placed on the 2nd column track; overflow does not occur if "grid-template-columns" value is "auto 1fr" and the grid item is placed on the 1st column track.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>margin-left causes grid item to overflow grid container in Firefox</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            .container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr;
                width: 320px;
                height: 320px;
                overflow: auto;
                background-color: whitesmoke;
            }
            .left {
                grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            }
            .item1,
            .item2 {
                grid-row-start: 1;
            }
            .item1,
            .left > .item2 {
                grid-column-start: 1;
            }
            .item2,
            .left > .item1 {
                grid-column-start: 2;
            }
            .item2 {
                width: 48px;
                transition: width 2s;
                background-color: silver;
            }
            .collapsed {
                width: 0;
            }
            .collapsed1 {
                width: 0.1px;
            }
            .inner {
                width: calc(100% - 16px);
                min-width: 0;
                height: 32px;
                margin: 8px;    /* causes overflow */
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .no_margins {
                margin: 0;
            }
            button {
                margin: 8px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            const margins = function () {
                document.querySelector('.inner').classList.toggle('no_margins');
            }
            const collapse0 = function () {
                let c = document.querySelector('.item2').classList;
                if (c.contains('collapsed1')) {
                    c.replace('collapsed1', 'collapsed')
                }
                else {
                    c.add('collapsed');
                }
            }
            const collapse1 = function () {
                let c = document.querySelector('.item2').classList;
                if (c.contains('collapsed')) {
                    c.replace('collapsed', 'collapsed1')
                }
                else {
                    c.add('collapsed1');
                }
            }
            const expand = function () {
                document.querySelector('.item2').classList.remove('collapsed', 'collapsed1');
            }
            const layout = function () {
                document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('left');
            }
            const load_handler = function () {
                let btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
                btns[0].addEventListener('click', margins);
                btns[1].addEventListener('click', collapse0);
                btns[2].addEventListener('click', collapse1);
                btns[3].addEventListener('click', expand);
                btns[4].addEventListener('click', layout);
            }
            addEventListener('load', load_handler); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item1">
                <button type="button">Toggle margins</button>
                <button type="button">Collapse to 0px</button>
                <button type="button">Collapse to 0.1px</button>
                <button type="button">Expand</button>
                <button type="button">Switch between 2 layouts</button>
            </div>
            <div class="item2">
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I discovered this in latest version of Firefox 120, I don't know since which version they first introduced the changes but I'm sure that earlier versions did not behave this way.
I could specify "visibility" for grid item as "auto" or "hidden" as workaround, or wrap the div that is contained in grid item in another div and specify the "visibility" as "auto" or "hidden" for the wrapper div but my question is if it's a bug or intended behavior which conforms to the specification related to Grid layout?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was confirmed as  [Bug 1868027](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1868027)